# How to get a results ouput file from running a copy operation against a server list?

Tags: batch-file, script, robocopy

We have a batch file that we use to (robo)copy scripts to various computers on our network.

We need be able to write the result of the copy operation (success or fail) to an output file including the server name.

Here is where I am at in the process and don't know how to proceed.

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (Maquinas_log.txt) do (

  robocopy.exe "E:\HERRAMIENTAS\SCRIPTS\ActualizarFirmas" \\%%i\c$\temp firmas.exe /R:1 /W:1

)
exit
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Please don't close this.  I think I get what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to know about is [ERRORLEVEL](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html).

If you use `call :label <params>`, you can break up the logic in ways you aren't doing here.  [There are ways to do it](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) without the `call :label` syntax but I prefer this method.

After running robocopy, you need to look at the ERRORLEVEL variable to determine success or not.  You could ALSO simply check if the file is there after the robocopy line.

Something like this:

```
@echo off

Set SalidaArchivo=%TEMP%\RobocopyResults.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (Maquinas_log.txt) do call :RoboCopyFileWithResults "%%i"
goto :EOF

:: Note: goto :EOF arriba es "volver a la función de llamada".. en este caso saldrá
:: Note: goto :EOF above means "return to the calling function" which in this case will exit the batch.

:: ----------------------------------------------------------------
:RoboCopyFileWithResults
  Set ServidorNombre=%~1
  robocopy.exe "E:\HERRAMIENTAS\SCRIPTS\ActualizarFirmas" \\%%i\c$\temp firmas.exe /R:1 /W:1
  echo %ServidorNombre%=%ERRORLEVEL% >>%SalidaArchivo%
  goto :EOF

:: Note: goto :EOF arriba es "volver a la función de llamada"
:: Note: goto :EOF above means "return to the calling function"
```